# How can I pause assigning values to LEDs in this Arduino game to wait for player input?

Tags: arduino

I'm making a small Arduino game.
A random binary number is created and displayed by 4 LEDs. (If it's 3 for example, the leds go 0011).
A player needs to guess it and press the button that number of times.
If you guessed right, you win and a separate result-LED blinks. If you lost, it turns on and stays long.

I'll post the code I have so far.
The problem is the LEDs just start blinking very quickly (so the random numbers get assigned) but the program is not waiting for user input.

Where is my mistake?

Ty

```
//declaring and initializing button and leds
int led1 = 9;
int led2 = 6;
int led3 = 5;
int led4 = 3;

int ledResult = 13; //will blink when you won, stay on when you lost

int buttonPin = 2;
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status
int buttonPushCounter = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;


long interval = 2000;

long randomNumber;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //starts serial communication

  pinMode (led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led4, OUTPUT);

  pinMode (ledResult, OUTPUT);

  pinMode (buttonPin, INPUT);

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0)); //the pin is unconnected so it'll return something random (0-1023)


}

void loop() {

  randomNumber = random(1, 16);

  Serial.println("Random Numbers sequence"); //just for self-check
  Serial.println(randomNumber);

  if (randomNumber >= 8)
   {
    digitalWrite (led1, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 8;
  }
  else
  {
   digitalWrite (led1, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber >= 4)
  {
    digitalWrite (led2, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 4;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led2, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber >= 2)
  {
    digitalWrite (led3, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 2;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led3, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber = 1)
  {
    digitalWrite (led4, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led4, LOW);
  }


 //READ BUTTON STATE
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
// compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {

unsigned long start = millis();
if ((millis() - start) >= interval); {

  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {

    buttonPushCounter++;
    Serial.println("Button push counter:");
    Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
  }
  // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
  delay(50);
}
// save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
lastButtonState = buttonState;

if (buttonPushCounter == randomNumber) {
  Serial.println("You won!");
  digitalWrite(ledResult, HIGH);
  delay(700);
  digitalWrite(ledResult, LOW);
  delay(700);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("You lost.");
  digitalWrite(ledResult, HIGH);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `if ((millis() - start) >= interval);` -> `if ((millis() - start) >= interval)` and many other corrections...

Comment: A lot of other corrections... also `if (randomNumber = 1)` -> `if (randomNumber == 1)`.. But first of all, how does it work? Now the device continuously changes the number (and so you can't choose one, since it changes before you can make a guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frarugi87 makes excellent points; this looks like a job for a state machine; once you get the random number, you then check to see if the number is correctly guessed.

One question - if the number is '5', and the person presses 5 times (but wanted to press '6'), wouldn't the system declare a 'win' after it saw 5 button presses?  Is there another 'enter' button?   Is there a timeout?

Notes on state machines...

[Arduino Switch to Turn a Relay timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977086/arduino-switch-to-turn-a-relay-timer/34387537#34387537)

Comment: thank you! i will check it. the problem you mentioned i haven't even thought about. maybe i'll add a timer for answer input and check the answer after it runs out.